Why does the value that is less than the minimum number of a function can be used as the result?
Consider this question
$$
\exists x >1, ax - 3 < 0
$$
This question asked what the range of a is.
When talking about the case where a > 0, the answer says it equals to require that the greatest lower bound of the function f(x) = ax - 3 is less than zero, the answer gives the step that:
f(1) < 0
so the result is a < 3. I am confused here. Since the value of x is larger than 1, and the function f(x) is monotonically increment when x ∈ R, the greatest lower bound of f(x) should be larger than f(1). why is f(1) < 0 sufficient here?

Because $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{3}{x}=3$.

"the minimum value of f(x) "  Who says there is a minimum value?  Lot's (most) functions bounded below do not have minimum values.  Consider the function $i(x) = x$, the identity function where $1< x < 3$.  What is that minimum value? There is no minimum value.  But there is an infinum value of $\inf i(x) = 1$.

@fleablood a > 0, the intended meaning here is that the greatest lower bound of f(x) = ax - 3 is less than zero. How f(1) is not that value because x > 1. why saying f(1) < 0 can make the greatest lower bound less than 0?

I'm not sure what you are asking.  But $\inf$ and $\sup$ need not actually be values in the set.  It is possible for all $w \in S$ to be $w > 0$ but to have $\inf w = 0$.  (Or to have all $u\in T$ to be $u <0$ and $\sup T = 0$.

Because $ax-3$ is continuous in $x$, if $a\cdot 1-3 \lt 0$ there will be some $x \gt 1$ such that $ax-3 \lt 0$.
If you define $f(x)$ as $ax-3$ for $x \gt 1$ you are correct that it has no minimum value (unless $a=0$).  The argument can probably be phrased correctly using the greatest lower bound, which does exist.

Because ax−3
is continuous in x
, if a⋅1−3<0
there will be some x>1
such that ax−3<0 why is this true? The greatest lower bound is larger than f(1), why let f(1) <0 can provide that greatest lower bound is less than 0?

For the first sentence, you can appeal to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity.  Take $\epsilon=-\frac {f(1)}2$.  Then $f(1+\delta) \lt f(1)+\epsilon \lt 0$ but the argument of $f$ is greater than $1$.  Understanding this is critical to understanding formal continuity.  For the second, the greatest lower bound is exactly $f(1)$ because if you give me a number greater than $f(1)$ I can find an $x\gt 1$ so that $f(x)$ is lower than that number, so your number is not a lower bound.

Thanks. This is the answer that I was asking. ϵ > 0, there exits δ > 0, for any x in  |x - x0| < δ, |f(x) - f(x0)| <  ϵ. This answers why f(1) < f(x) < 0.
